# How to open a page in a new tab using an id and target _blank

Tags: javascript

How to open a page in a new tab using an `id` and target `_blank`:

```
let id = 323;
window.open('edit.php?id=' + id + ',' + '_blank');
```

result - `edit.php?id=323,_blank`

I need - `edit.php?id=323`

Thanks.

Comment: this way: `window.open('edit.php?id=' + id, '_blank');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concatenation logic is wrong. Do it like this.

```
window.open('edit.php?id=' + id, '_blank');
```

Pass '_blank' as the second parameter. Do not concatenate it.

Answer (score 1):

pass '_blank' as the second argument to `window.open`

```
let id = 323;
window.open('edit.php?id=' + id, '_blank');
```